# Error in sending dataframe from R to NetLogo during loop

Tags: r, netlogo

NetLogo Users,

I have another trouble with the function "NLDfToList" in "RNetLogo" package.

The observable formats are correct in data.frame., however,

```
Error in NLCommand(set.base, set.values, nl.obj = nl.obj) :
```

constantly appears when I try to sending dataframe to netlogo during loop.

What I am trying to do is sending data in the middle of the loop and with this data, calculating in NetLogo Go command and again sending resulting ouput.

Can't I do that in NetLogo and R?, I wonder.

If you need any specific detail, I would please to add.

Thank you very much for your help~!

Comment: How are lists defined in NetLogo model and what structure has the input data frame? Is there any error description printed above this "Error in NLCommand .... "?

Comment: 1. NetLogo has lists with the same name in the global[],     2. And dataframe in R has 'num' in it,       3. Nope, this error is all that I've got

Comment: Oh, there were "arguments imply differing number of rows: 8, 0" error messages, so that transpose them then it became character value.